# Monotone Subsequences

Tags: real-analysis

My analysis book says that the fact that every sequence has a monotone subsequence is "quite surprising and not at all obvious." The proof does not seem so much more difficult or ingenious than any other proof. Why are they claiming it's so surprising?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

I've had a silly moment, I initially put this (corrected)

---

Every BOUNDED sequence has a convergent subsequence, (monotone is a musical term BTW - monotonic). This is quite surprising! **Bolzano Weierstrass Theorem theorem**

Think of 2 horizontal lines, those are out bounds, now put ANY sequence you like in there, as jagged or smooth, or jagged with smooth bits and goes up and down a lot and does whatever you want. It has a convergent subsequence! There's a subsequence there that converges to a number! (it may have more than one too!)

This is .... once you've seen it is obvious, but before hand you wouldn't have thought without a moment's hesitation that there are convergent subsequences in that! Hence non-obvious.

---

But I never actually answered the question:

Imagine a sequence, and draw any violent or smooth, or jagged or diverging sequence you like, it does not look AT ALL like any part of it is monotonic (especially not if you link the points) BUT it does. Now obvious is "1/n tends towards zero", real analysis hit me like a shovel my first year, I was like "Of course it is, it's not going to tend to 5 is it!" BUT that's because it is obvious, it requires no measurable amount of time to conclude that.

If I gave you a violent sequence as described above, only after knowing what you know now could you instantly see the subsequences (greatest lower bound and lowest upper bound within first n terms as the nth value of two subsequences come to mind, monotonically increasing and decreasing respectively, (but not strictly! they could be equal) come right to mind). This is what it refers to.

At A-level I would have seen this /at some point/ especially if the question or task lead me towards it, but I would not be able to see it like I can the truly obvious things.

I love maths because what has been seen cannot be unseen, you may forget but you can always derive, what I call obvious is always expanding. Monotonically and strictly increasing itself, stick that sequence on a metric space defined by an ordering of the chronological order I learn things in, use time being continuous and the MVT or IVT to deduce stuff, I dare ya.

Comment: they prove in my book that it does not have to be bounded

Comment: @PaulMalinowski fixed, sorry about that.